# Плавное появление background-color и исчезновение через две секунды

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Мне нужно чтобы плавно появлялся и исчезал только  `background-color:red;`, а не целый блок, как на моем примере.

```js
 $("#button_1").click(function() {
   $("#div3").fadeIn(2000);
 });

 $("#button_2").click(function() {
   $("#div3").fadeOut(2000);
 });
```

```css
#div3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
  background-color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
.but {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #00748f;
  height: 25px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #0483a0;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="but" id="button_1">Показать</div>
<br>
<div class="but" id="button_2">Скрыть</div>
<br>


<div id="div3">Текст</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тогда так:

```
<style type="text/css">
#div3 {
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 100px; height: 100px;
}
.but {
    background-color: #0483a0;
    border: 1px solid #00748f;
    color: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px; height: 25px;
}
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="but" id="button_1">Показать</div>
<div class="but" id="button_2">Скрыть</div>
<div id="div3">Текст</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#button_1').click(function() {
    $('#div3')
        .css('background-color', 'red')
        .css('transition', '2s');
});

$('#button_2').click(function() {
    $('#div3')
        .css('background-color', 'transparent')
        .css('transition', '2s');
});
</script>
```